# Cannot open a missing lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Probably my question is a stupid question made by a newbie programmer but I'm stuck and don't know how to fix it.

I downloaded a [project](https://github.com/VirtuosoChris/VirtuosoConsole) and tried to compile it. But it gives a `LNK1104    cannot open file VirtuosoConsole.lib` error, which I know a lib is missing but i don't know if I must compile it from source files or what I have to do. In case I have to build it, what I have to do to do it?

Thx for the help.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cmake project should create the VirtuosoConsole library.

It is a cmake project, so you need to have cmake installed and run cmake on the project to generate the make files for visual studio to use.

Comment: Aha, I generate the project with CMake, but i dont find any lib in any folder, maybe i'm using CMake incorrectly but don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you need to build the project generated by CMake

Comment: When I generate the project I start it with VS and build the ALL_BUILD solution. Then is when the error apears.